# Space Invaders - accessing all the alien prefabs in the scene to increase their speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started out learning to code (C#) in Unity and I'm well on the way creating my own Space Invaders clone but I'm stuck on the logic of incrementally increasing the speed of ALL the alien prefabs in the game now I have them moving left to right and down. I would be grateful if someone could provide me with/or explain the coding logic on how to do this?

Comment: Instead of modifying every alien in the scene to increase its speed, consider having a publicly-accessible variable somewhere that all these aliens reference to define their speed. This way, you only need to modify this single variable, and what each alien does with it is up to them.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in unity to give prefabs a tag. It is then possible to access all prefabs with a specific tag. This is a great way to deal with multiple prefabs as it allows you to group prefabs in whatever way you want.

This is a javascript snippet, but it applies to c# as well.

```js
function makechild(){
  objs =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("things to group");
  for (obj in objs){
    obj.transform.parent = parentObj.transform;
  }
}
```

Another way would be to create a publicly accessible variable that you can apply to all of your prefabs however it would be slightly less flexible, of course it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

in c#

```
GameObject[] spaceinvader;
int length;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    spaceinvader = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("your tag");
    length = spaceinvader.Length;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void increasespeed()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        spaceinvader[i].GetComponent<yourspeedscript>().speed += 1;
    }
}
```

this should work if your speed/movement is controlled by another script but if not, you can easily increment the space invader speed in the increasespeed() function.